# What is $\mathbb{Q}_l/\mathbb{Z}_l$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $l$ be a prime number, is there an easy description of $\mathbb{Q}_l/\mathbb{Z}_l$?

Comment: Do you want the quotient of these two, as groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there’s an easy description, it’s the $\ell$-primary part of $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$, in other words, isomorphic to the group of $\ell$-power roots of unity (as a subgroup of the circle subgroup of $\Bbb C^\times$, if you wish).

You can think of the $\ell$-primary part of $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ as the rational numbers of form $m/\ell^n$, modulo integers. You can see that this group maps injectively into $\Bbb Q_\ell/\Bbb Z_\ell$, and I’ll leave it to you to show that the map is also a surjection.